# how can i use mapping on structure inside another structure and create some elements

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, function

i want to create some Pledges for Startup there are these structures:

```
struct Startup {
     address payable founder;
     string title;
     string startupDescription;
     uint goal;
     uint backers;
     uint startAt;
     uint endsAt;
     bool status;
     mapping (uint => Pledge) pledges;
    }
struct Pledge {
    string title;
    string pledgeDescription;
    uint cost;
    }
```

i tried something like this:

```
function newStartup (string memory _title, string memory _startupDescription, uint _goal, uint _duration, uint _pledgesCount) external {
    Startup memory newStartup = Startup({
            founder: payable(msg.sender),
            title: _title,
            startupDescription: _startupDescription,
            goal: _goal,
            startAt: block.timestamp,
            endsAt: block.timestamp + duration,
            status: true
        });
}
```

but got

```
Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.
```

how can i initialize some Pledges in Startup when i call the function? as i know function in function doesn't work in Solidity

Answer (score 0):

I will try using an array instead of the mapping.

```
struct Startup {
     address payable founder;
     string title;
     string startupDescription;
     uint goal;
     uint backers;
     uint startAt;
     uint endsAt;
     bool status;
     Pledge[] pledges;  // array of Pledge
}
```

When making a new startup we can initialize some pledges like this:

```
function newStartup (string memory _title, string memory _startupDescription, uint _goal, uint _duration, Pledge[] calldata _pledges) external {
    Startup memory newStartup = Startup({
        founder: payable(msg.sender),
        title: _title,
        startupDescription: _startupDescription,
        goal: _goal,
        startAt: block.timestamp,
        endsAt: block.timestamp + duration,
        status: true,
        pledges: _pledges,  // added this
    });

    // ...
}
```

We can add a new pledge by pushing the array:

```
function newPledge(Pledge _pledge, /*...*/) external {
    // grab the startup from storage here
    Startup storage startup = // ...

    startup.pledges.push(_pledge);
}
```

To remove a pledge knowing its index in the array:

```js
function removePledge(uint256 _pledgeIndex, /*...*/) external {
    // grab the startup from storage here
    Startup storage startup = // ...

    uint256 length = startup.pledges.length;
    require(_pledgeIndex < length, "Index over length");

    // copy last element in the index, then pop()
    Pledge memory lastPledge = startup.pledges[length-1];
    startup.pledges[_pledgeIndex] = lastPledge;
    startup.pledges.pop();
}
```